# How do I write a new #%datum function to catch all strings?

Tags: racket

I want to write a new racket language that catches and deals with strings in some special way. I've written the following example code:

```
#lang racket

(provide #%top #%app #%top-interaction #%module-begin
         (rename-out [datum #%datum]))

(define big-string "")

(define (add-string x)
  (set! big-string (string-append big-string x)))

(define-syntax (datum stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ . x)
     #'(if (string? x)
           (#%datum . (add-string x))
           (#%datum . x))]))
```

It gives me an out of memory error when I try to use the target language. Is it recursively calling itself? I would have thought that hygiene would prevent that.

Perhaps the problem is that #%datum returns syntax, rather than datums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's look at the problem with version of datum above.
Let's say the program contains the string `"a"`.
The expander sees the string `"a"` and turns it in to `(#%datum . "a")`.
Since `#%datum` is bound to `datum` defined as:

```
(define-syntax (datum stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ . x)
     #'(if (string? x)
           (#%datum . (add-string x))
           (#%datum . x))]))
```

The syntax `(#%datum . "a")` will expand to

```
       (if (string? "a")
           (#%datum . (add-string "a"))
           (#%datum . "a"))
```

The expander will then begin to expand the above expression.
When it comes to the first `"a"` it will expand it into `(#%datum . "a")`
which becomes `(datum . "a")` which then becomes another copy of

```
       (if (string? "a")
           (#%datum . (add-string "a"))
           (#%datum . "a"))
```

etc.

The intention of the `datum` were to use two different expansions either `(add-string x)` or `(#%datum . x)`. However since the output of `datum` is `#'(if (string? x) ...)` the `if` isn't evaluated at compile time, but at runtime.

The solution is to move the `if`.

```
#lang racket

(provide #%top #%app #%top-interaction #%module-begin
         (rename-out [datum #%datum]))

(define big-string "")

(define (add-string x)
  (set! big-string (string-append big-string x))
  x)

(define-syntax (datum stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ . x)
     (if (string? (syntax-e #'x))
         #'(add-string (#%datum . x))
         #'(#%datum . x))]))
```

Besides moving the `if` I have altered the `add-string` consequence.

Note: If a macro use expands into a use of the same macro, 
      then you are likely to run into this infinite expansion problem.
      The easiest way to find the culprit is to use the macro stepper.
      Turn the "Macro hiding:" setting to "Disable". Then step until you 
      see the loop.

Comment: Looks like `add-string` needs to have `x` as it's last form to get the form to evaluate to somethig other than `#<void>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer.